# SQL Reporting Services Javascript to change reportviewer page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I'm using the ReportViewer control in a WebForm. I see from the link below that there is a JavaScript API for interacting with it so you can create your own UI instead of the default toolbar:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx

What I don't see is anyway to set the report's current page to implement (first, prev, next, last) commands.

How can this be done in JavaScript? I'm currently using VS 2012.

Comment: Which version of ReportViewer are you using >8 or <=8 (you have both tags for SSRS 2008 and 2005 on your question).

Comment: Version 11. That's what comes w/ Visual studio 2012.